# How to get the speed of a network card on the command line?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line

I am trying to see what the speed of some network cards on a remote server. 
Our reporting software says they are 10Mbps, but I am sure that is wrong they should be 1Gbps. Our monitoring software uses SNMP to query the servers, perhaps the servers are reporting information incorrectly.

`ifconfig` does not report what the speed of the devices are. How can I see what the currently configured speed of the cards are.

---

Updated

When I ran the commands mii-tool and ethtool I got the following errors. 
We are running Centos5 on a xen virtual machine.

> $ mii-tool -v
>   SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth0' failed: Operation not supported
>   SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth1' failed: Operation not supported
>   no MII interfaces found
>   $ ethtool eth1
>   Settings for eth1:
>     Link detected: yes
>   $ ethtool eth0
>   Settings for eth0:
>     Link detected: yes

I notice the ethtool on my personal computer brings up a lot more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `ethtool`. It will show you the current negotiated value and the available values.

```
ethtool eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the supposed error in your reporting software comes from that it internally uses `mii-tool` and then parses the output. This was some sort of standard up until quite a few years ago, and `mii-tool` is now deprecated since it lacks support for most (all?) Gbps configurations.

As said in Keith's answer: use `ethtool` instead; it's continuously updated. I just wanted to give some plausible background to the reporting error, and a possible way of fixing the problem if you have access to the code.